# How to sort the data in alphanumeric values

Tags: sql

I have these values: `d1, d45, d79, d33, d100`

I want to sort these variables in ascending order from my table.

What is the query to get the output as:

```
d1
d33
d45
d79
d100
```

Comment: What database?  MySQL, sql-server, oracle, ...?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a "natural sort". For Microsoft SQL Server 2005, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005). For other languages, see (for example) [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127913/sorting-strings-is-much-harder-than-you-thought).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not SQL answer at all. :) For variant with one letter only order by length and alpha.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee a pattern of /\w\d+/ ...

In postgres:

```
select foo from bar order by cast(substring(foo from 2) as int)
```

..and similar will exist for other SQL flavours. Expensive mind.

edit: androids solution looks good too:

```
..order by char_length(foo),foo
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that the data values only contain the letter d and a numeric value, then you can also use:

```
select column from YourTable
order by convert(int, replace(column, 'd', ''))
```

If it contains any other letters, then this method rapidly becomes unusable:

```
select column from YourTable
order by convert(int, 
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
            column, 'a', ''),
                'b', ''),
                'c', ''),
                'd', ''), 
                'e', '')
        )
```