# Return value from database without the HTML tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

In my database **MYDB** I have a table called **MYTABLE** and I have a column called **Description**. I am saving a long description in there with multiple HTML tags.

How can i return the values and not include all the HTML tags?

Is this even possible? What will be the best way of doing this? In the SQL statement or in code behind? And how will I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See following
[Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use some form of HTML parsing. If it is for basic HTML parsing then some form of [Regex](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2003/05/13/6963.aspx) should suffice. However, for more advanced parsing you should look at something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). I use this to parse emails and I must say it works pretty well.