# Strip Html tags from a SQL result

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, strip

How do I strip html tags for several rows in my sql select query?

I saw this function [SQL SERVER – 2005 – UDF – User Defined Function to Strip HTML – Parse HTML – No Regular Expression](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/) but it works I think for a single select output where as my select has many output rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate question, and duplicate answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server (which I only found through google, not searching on SO itself).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the function you cited on a multirow result set.

```
SELECT dbo.udf_StripHTML(yt.YourHTMLColumn)
    FROM YourTable yt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a valid xml you can use:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT( XML, TEXT_OR_COLUMN_NAME ).value( '.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) as TextR
FROM [TABLE]
```