# TSQL - Replacing or removing a string between two dissimilar strings, multiple times in a field for an entire column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to replace or remove all characters between and including these  two characters < >  they occur numerous times throughout the field and in varying circumstances for each row

I believe the strings to be replaced are html so when I tried to post an example the site just registered it as formatting.

I used replace to remove all common strings such as the the html for line break but some vary field to field using hexadecimal color values.

Thanks!

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/457701/210908

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE(TAGS VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @foo VALUES('<fname>John</fname><lname>Dewey</lname>');

SELECT 1; --This will initialize @@ROWCOUNT if necessary. Might be optional depending on your query
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
    UPDATE @foo
    SET TAGS = STUFF(TAGS,CHARINDEX('<',TAGS),CHARINDEX('>',TAGS) - CHARINDEX('<',TAGS) + 1,'')
    WHERE TAGS LIKE '%<%>%'
END
SELECT * FROM @foo;
```

Result

```
------------------------
JohnDewey
```

Comment: This is good, but it will only do this to the first instance. OP needed this to work for "they occur numerous times throughout the field "

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #html(Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #html(Value) VALUES('<ShouldBeRemoved>1 <Remove>abc<also remove>def<Take this out>ghi')
INSERT INTO #html(Value) VALUES('<ShouldBeRemoved>2 <Remove>abc<also remove>def<Take this out>ghi')
INSERT INTO #html(Value) VALUES('<ShouldBeRemoved>3 <Remove>abc<also remove>def<Take this out>ghi')

;with Cte(Value) AS (
    SELECT Value FROM #html
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REPLACE(Value, SUBSTRING(Value, CHARINDEX('<', Value), CHARINDEX('>', Value) - CHARINDEX('<', Value) + 1),'')
    FROM Cte
    WHERE CHARINDEX('<', Value) != 0
)
SELECT Value FROM Cte
WHERE CHARINDEX('<', Value) = 0
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

DROP TABLE #html
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. I tested it and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_RemoveHtmlTag] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE((CHARINDEX('<', @HTMLText)>0) and (CHARINDEX('>', @HTMLText)>0))
    Begin
        SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HtmlText,SUBSTRING(@HTMLText, CHARINDEX('<', @HTMLText), CHARINDEX('>', @HTMLText) - CHARINDEX('<', @HTMLText) + 1),'');       
    End

    RETURN @HTMLText
END
GO
```

Then how to use this func

```
select [dbo].[udf_RemoveHtmlTag]([column_name]) from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for them who wants to avoid calling UDF (User Defined Function). 
Assuming that one of your sql table col. contains HTML tags like below and you want to remove everything between `<` and `>` .
`[Remark] =" the HTML tags like:   < div > < p >< span > We are trying to contact the company (Tel:&nbsp;< /span >< span> < /p > < /div > etc'  "`

**Step#1:** Store your result set to a Temp table

```
select .... into #t1 from....where...blah blah
```

**Step#2:** Use the following code to remove everything between < and > and update the field.

```
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
    UPDATE #t1
    SET [Remark] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(STUFF([Remark],CHARINDEX('<',[Remark]),CHARINDEX('>',[Remark]) - CHARINDEX('<',[Remark]) + 1,'') )), CHAR(9), ' '), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(11), ' '), CHAR(12), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '), '&nbsp;', '')))
    WHERE [Remark] LIKE '%<%>%'
END
```

**Step#3**: Select your desired result from Temp table

```
SELECT * FROM #t1
```