# How to write a SQL query to remove html links in Magento description?

Tags: mysql, magento

I have thousands of products that include the following in the longDescription field:

```
<ul>
<li>Some content</li>
<li><a href="link"... </li>
</ul>

Several trailing line breaks...
```

I'm wondering if there is a safe and effective SQL query that can remove the `<li>'s` with the links in them, as well as the trailing line breaks / empty characters?

Comment: Does this have to be done in SQL? It might be easier to grab the data from the database, manipulate it in some general purpose language, then update the rows with the results.

Comment: You could try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server

Comment: I was thinking of doing it in ruby, as I'm no php expert, but the setup seemed longer than a quick SQL statement -- assuming someone knows one.

Answer (score 1):

Best way might be to add a frontend model to the attribute. Create a model that extends  `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract` and remove the HTML in the `getValue()` function e.g. using `strip_tags()`.