# Ignoring html tags in SQL Server 2008 columns when creating views

Tags: html, sql-server-2008

I have a database table which holds email communications. The column in the table that holds the main message details holds the message header and all associated message header and message body HTML tags as well as the email text. An example entry in this column could be:

```
<sender tag details...> 
   <email header details> 
   <more header details> 
   <font: Arial Bold, 14>Hi Joe</font><br> <br>Here are the details requested.<br> <br>Steve.
```

From this I want to extract into a view only:

```
Hi Joe<br> <br>Here are the details requested.<br> <br>Steve.
```

i.e. I do not want or need header details or anything to do with fonts, but I do need the text and spacing.

Database is SQL Server 2008, column's datatype is `text`. I do not have the option of modifying the source table or column, hence why it has to be a view.

In VB I would read in each line, look for `<>` tags and if the value between them wasn't `br` I'd simply ignore and move onto the next element of the line. Struggling to see how to accomplish the same thing in SQL Server?

Any thoughts?

Stu

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server) may help

Comment: Ian - spot on thanks. Don't understand why that didn't come up in a search though? However - does exactly what I require - thanks.