# PHP Search Function Returns HTML BR Tag

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search function on my site that looks through posts on a forum.  The search is performed using a MySQL SELECT statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE post_text LIKE '%$search_string%';
```

When a match is made, I return the found posts and highlight the term(s) within the original posts.

```
function highlight_finds($search_text, $search_for){
   $replacement_string = "<mark>".$search_for."</mark>";
   $replaced_text = str_ireplace($search_for, $replacement_string, $search_text);
   return $replaced_text;
}

echo highlight_finds(stripslashes($post_text), $search_string);
```

Line breaks are accounted for with "br" inside the database table.

```
 line 1 <br /> <br /> line 2 <br /> <br /> line 3
```

When I run my highlight_finds function on the above using the search term "br", the following HTML is returned

```
line 1 <<mark>br</mark> /><<mark>br</mark> />line 2 
<<mark>br</mark> /><<mark>br</mark> />line 3
```

The mark tag is placed around the br tag and any posts with line breaks are returned in the results and displayed with the br tags.

What's the best way to prevent returning line break tags when searching for the terms "br", "b", or "r"?

Comment: You can do that by not having HTML in your database, which is bad practice to begin with.

Comment: Either you have to filter your results with php or you have to store your db entries additional to existings result without html tags.

Comment: You could try [Full Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) in which you can define stopwords that are ignored when searching. It is also much more faster than `LIKE '%search%'`.

Comment: You can also create your own mysql function like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Give me a break, every CMS or blog has HTML in the database. "bad practice" seriously? Why?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Easy, because a relational database is for relational data. HTML is not relational data. It's a markup, and it should be kept in a file, or as a template. If you must, keep your data formatted using some sort of mediary format, such as Markdown in the database, and convert to HTML back when outputting to the browser. Also, just because every CMS or blog has HTML in the database, doesn't make it good practice. May I remind you we're talking of WordPress, Joomla, MediaWiki, etc here?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Get real man, that's the way it's done. Is Markdown "relational data"? What about Stack Overflow, or Ebay? You don't think they keep our HTML in the database?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: That's what my experience tells me. And storing HTML in the database is a gateway to problems. We're polluting this thread though. Feel free to join us at the [PHP room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `strip_tags` while you are searching try with mysql custom function

```
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x longtext) RETURNS longtext
LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE sstart INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ends INT UNSIGNED;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
REPEAT
SET ends = LOCATE('>', x, sstart);
SET x = CONCAT(SUBSTRING( x, 1 ,sstart -1) ,SUBSTRING(x, ends +1 )) ;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
UNTIL sstart < 1 END REPEAT;
return x;
END;

SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE strip_tags(post_text) LIKE '%$search_string%';
```

**Edit**

OR in php you can use `strip_tags()`

```
function highlight_finds($search_text, $search_for){
   $replacement_string = "<mark>".$search_for."</mark>";
   $replaced_text = str_ireplace($search_for, $replacement_string, strip_tags($search_text));
   return $replaced_text;
}
```

[Reference](http://youropensource.com/projects/626-strip_tags-in-mysql)

[Removing HTML tags using mysql](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,177343,177985)

[Php strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)