# update column to remove html tags

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am upgrading my db from one version of application to other. In this the later version does not store html tags but the previous one does.
I have sql function to remove html tags from one string :[Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

However I need to update all rows of one column. Can anyone please suggest some script so that all rows are updated removing the the html tags

Comment: Why can't you use this function? Update the same row with function return data?

Comment: I tried 
update table t1
set column=[dbo].[udf_StripHTML](select column from t1 where pk_id=t.pk_id)
But I cannot pass select query as the parameter it seems

Comment: Can't you do like  `update table t1 set columnName=udf_StripHTML (columnName)`??

Comment: it says udf_StripHTML is not a built in function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDF stands for "user defined function" - unless you did not define the the function with the name "udf_StripHTML" this simply won't work. I think you refer to this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML]
(@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0
AND @End > 0
AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

to test this function do:

```
SELECT dbo.udf_StripHTML('<b>UDF at stackoverflow.com </b><br><br><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow.com</a>')
```

Result Set:

UDF at stackoverflow.com Stackoverflow.com

This function was set up by Pinal Dave - [see here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks that worked. I had renamed the function which caused the problem

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to cast your vote or mark an answer as correct. This will also help other users looking for an answer.