# How to remove pay day loans seo spam injections in sql server?

Tags: asp.net, xss

The sql server database for my site is infected with pay day loans seo spam. Following code is injected into some fields:

```
</title><style>.am1j{position:absolute;clip:rect(463px,auto,auto,463px);}</style><div class=am1j>We all they should <a href=http://proofpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> be embarrassed the purposes for them.</div></title><style>.am1j{position:absolute;clip:rect(463px,auto,auto,463px);}</style><div class=am1j>We all they should <a href=http://proofpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a> be embarrassed the purposes for them.</div></a>
```

My site is written in asp.net and not using any component or plugin.
How is this code injected into the database? and how can I get rid of it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What/how are you doing, filtering/checking user input in your `<forms/>`?

Comment: Actually no input checking is done, but it is captcha protected. You mean it's due to that? How to get rid of it? Both in programming(Before injection) and in database(After injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually no input checking is done, but it is captcha protected.

### Never trust the client.

Therefore the answer is: **Validate and sanitize** all user/client inputs *before* processing/accepting (before its persisted in some way, e.g. db).

All you're doing is with CAPTCHA is mitigating replay/robots. Anyone can enter *anything* in your implementation.

An (unknowing) user with an infected system (that then mangles forms entries or intercepts client HTTP communications - e.g. injecting whatever html/script without user knowledge) will get past CAPTCHA.

Depending on your CAPTCHA/form handler implementation, a bot can even get past CAPTCHA by simply POSTing to your form handler (skipping your web page altogether).

- [Validating User Input in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7kh55542(v=vs.100).aspx) and you can Bing/Google for more - references are extensive (regular expressions, etc.)
- [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457701/304683)

Hth...