# Striping HTML from data in MySQL database column

Tags: php, mysql, strip-tags

Probably based on this question: [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Think of me as a noob. I have a field with data in it. I need to strip html from this column and I'm aware that there is a PHP function that does this. What do I do to do this in my SQL database?

What do I enter for the query? Select my column (the field I call it) from the table...and then?

Comment: You select the column from the table preferable along with an id of some sort. Then clean them and then update them, this is where the id comes in handy. So you will know you are updating the correct row.

Comment: Isn't it easier to strip HTML before you place things in your database?

Comment: I assume you're not using SQL-Server, because that other question explains how to do it there. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: So you want to strip html from database without PHP but strictly by sql? that is because you're aware of the `strip_tags()` function.

Comment: I want to use PHP but dont know wher it go

Comment: So, shall I show you how to do it with PHP?

Comment: Please do so, would appreciate it

Comment: Worked thanks, I knw my question had minimal info but that was the jist of it.

Comment: That's why I asked you first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `strip_tag()` function

```
// assuming that you're using MySQL
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT column FROM table");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo strip_tags($row['column']) . '<br />';
}
```

or using `preg_replace()` function and this simple regular expression `<[^>]*>`

```
echo preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $row['column']);
```

[Working PHP demo](http://ideone.com/UGJgu1)

Recomended method: `strip_tags()` function in this case. It takes two arguments; the first one is the text itself and the second one contains `allowed tags`; so, for instance, if you want to keep `<a>` and clean everything else you simply use it like this:

```
strip_tags($text, '<a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not a MS SQL user, but as i have seen the link you posted. its all explained there. All you need is to create a function by copy pasting that code.

```
//Function From the Link Given in Question

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML]
(@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0
AND @End > 0
AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

and i guess you can use query like this using the function above.

```
select * from table where dbo.udf_StripHTML(Content1) like ‘%Hello%’
```

im not sure about the above query, but i think it would be something like that. However the above function defined, just try to use in query, may be it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but paste this where?

Comment: @ObiWanKobi somewhere in your code.. where it's above the query because if you go use functions you haven't defined yet you're gonna have a bad time.