# How to replace special character '<' from string in SQL server?

Tags: html, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, special-characters

I am inserting a dynamic html string to a  tag in HTML from SQL server.

When the HTML string contain the '<' character, it is not working well in front UI.

I have create fiddle for your reference 
http://jsfiddle.net/Loxr10nn/

I want to replace `'<'` character from the HTML string. If there is exact match found like Character `< ANY WORD without space` otherwise take as it is.

if character "`STEP ONE DIET <THAN 200 MG CHOL/DAY INCREASE EXERCISE`" then it will problematic for parsing.
otherwise `"< THAN"` then it will work fine.

When Inserting that string to MS SQL server then I want to replace `<THAN` with `< THAN` if found any this type of word then it should be replaced.. I want to do it in SQL server procedure..

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/6cew0do3/1/

Comment: htmlentities() ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: @RST no php code will work for me. I am looking in MSSQL server.. working in C# with MSSqlsever

Comment: why don't you use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` in c# ?

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire I am set html content using javascript by webservice call so It would not possible. It would be possible to check at time of save in MsSql server.

Comment: You can use a function to strip HTML tags. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server).

Comment: @AgentSQL I run the SQL function as given link, it not working. I check in fiddle, see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cdaad/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.. I appreciate @Steoleary code too,

```
DECLARE @Notes varchar(max)
SET @Notes = 'STEP ONE DIET <THAN 200 MG CHOL/DAY INCREASE EXERCISE, Test <  Single space before and after presever spacing'
SELECT @Notes AS BEFORE, REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(@Notes AS  VARCHAR(MAX)),'<', '< '), '<  ','< ') AS AFTER

--BEFORE
STEP ONE DIET <THAN 200 MG CHOL/DAY INCREASE EXERCISE, Test <  Single space before and after presever spacing
--AFTER ( Spacing around '<' is preserved )
STEP ONE DIET < THAN 200 MG CHOL/DAY INCREASE EXERCISE, Test <  Single space before and after presever spacing
```

Answer (score 1):

So depending on where you want to do this, either in C# or on the SQL server itself, generally doing it in the app and then storing it in SQL server already formatted is best) you can do it like this:

C#:

```
string original = "STEP ONE DIET <THAN 200 MG CHOL/DAY INCREASE EXERCISE";
string replaced = original.Replace(@"<", "< ");
```

Then insert the string replaced into your database rather than the original string

SQL Server:

You could do this either when writing your string to the database or everytime when you retrieve it:

```
REPLACE('STEP ONE DIET <THAN 200 MG CHOL/DAY INCREASE EXERCISE','<','< ')
```

Comment: I set the Text to textarea so it will display &lt; in textarea so It would worthless for me. It will possible if I add space between '<' and THAN then it will work.. '<THAN' should convert with '< THAN' then it will work

Comment: All you need to do then is modify the code in my answer and change the "&lt;" to "< " to get your desired result.

Comment: Hello @steoleary, I also preserver my space in string. so I am posting the solution my self.. You are right your code working but if there is '<' character then it will replace with space. but if already space will there then it will added one more space after '<' character.