# How delete tags from rows table of sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a `table` (SQLITE) that in this `table`, my data are in Tags . I need that delete all tags from this `table` . In the below image I need that delete tags (`<p></p>`, `<br></br`> etc..).

[image]

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Profile SET _Family= replace( _Family, '<p>', '' ) ;
```