# Sql injected code is inserted to my database . How to remove it

Tags: sql-server

One of my sql table is injected with some html code. It is inserted such that the html tags are inserted after actual data. How to remove this from my table.

Comment: What is the problem? As long as you escape HTML before you show your data, you are home free. This is not sql-injection though, it's stored XSS, and only if you don't escape HTML.

Comment: Is it the problem of server security or the code which  i  have written

Comment: That depends, but in itself storing html in the database is not a problem. The problem occurs only if you show it as html, that being that you don't escape the HTML value, so that the browser interprets it as html. If you escape it, it will just be shown as text (xml). Whether you escape things on the way in (before storing) or on the way out (before showing) is up to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that html code starts with symbol `<`. Then:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET SomeColumn = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<', SomeColumn) > 0 
                      THEN SUBSTRING(SomeColumn, 1, CHARINDEX('<', SomeColumn) - 1) 
                      ELSE SomeColumn END
```

If this is not true then we will need more information about data. May be it will not be possible at all...

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing more about your problem I can only advise to look for typical patterns of the unwanted stuff and then run some `UPDATE`s with suitable `REPLACE()` statements in it.

*If you had been using MySql ...* I simply didn't see the SQL-server tag ;-/

... a shorter version of Giorgi's solution would have been:

```
UPDATED tableName SET infestedCol=substring_index(infestedCol,'<',1)
```

Unfortunately you cannot use regular expressions for the search pattern here and it must be of the correct case.

Most of all, make sure you don't get more of the stuff, so secure your user forms further.

Comment: Karan Foto Electronics<div style="display:none">why do married men cheat on their wives <a href="http://www.harshpande.net/blogengine/page/husbandwatcheswifecheat">why do men cheat on their wife</a> click</div><div style="display:none">

Comment: this is one of my sample data

Comment: in this only "Karan Foto Electricals " is the orginal data. Other is injected. How to remove that . This code is afftected in full table. The table contains more than 3000 rows