# SQL Server- Bulk Export Data without html formatting and line spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to export some Database data into a text file. My Query looks like this:

```
SELECT Category1, Category2, Category3 
FROM dbo.tbl1
WHERE Category1 = 'JP-4'
AND Category2> 4;
```

This works fine to get the data, however there is some html formatting in the table entries such as
`<p>,</p>,<br>,</br>` etc. So ideally I need to remove those when exporting the data to the text file. I've tried to do it with a simple replace query but that didn't work.
I've also got an issue with line splits and would need to remove the (\n\r).
Any suggestions on how to do this would be really appreciated!

The Data format is something like this:

```
Category1: JP-4
Category2: 4
Category3:<p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor</p>  <p>amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
Category4:<p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor</p>
```

I got it to work with:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE("Category3",'<p>',''),'</p>','') 
FROM dbo.tbl1
WHERE Category1= 'JP-4'
AND Category2> 4;
```

But the issue is that I've got 15 columns in total and that I need to do it for several different tags for each column and I thought there must be a better/more efficient way of doing it.
I've looked all over the internet but couldn't really find a solution.

Comment: Duplicate, please check [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Comment: I've tried the code in the post but can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to strip out non alpha-numeric characters for situations similar to this.  The full code is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGENStripNonAlphaNumChars (
    @inputString nvarchar(max)
)

RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @keepChars nvarchar(50) = '%[^a-z0-9 ]%' --a-z, 0-9, space

WHILE PatIndex(@keepChars, @inputString) > 0
    BEGIN
       set @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, PatIndex(@keepChars, @inputString), 1, '');
    END


RETURN @inputString;

END;
```

The key is in what you use the patindex function to look for.  I set @keepChars  = '%[^a-z0-9 ]%', which means that it finds anything that is NOT (the carrot - ^) either an alphabetic or numeric character.  You should be able to tweak the criteria you pass to patindex to get the results you want (note that patindex does not do regular expressions).

Hopefully that points you in a helpful direction.

EDIT:

After further review, here is an approach that more closely targets html code specifically (see also [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)):

```
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@inputString)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@inputString,CHARINDEX('<',@inputString))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
    SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString,@Start,@Length,'')
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@inputString)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@inputString,CHARINDEX('<',@inputString))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END

RETURN @inputString;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. Silly question- Can I add the function just to to the Source Query of the SQL Server Export Wizard?

Comment: You would create the function in the database, and then refer to it in your query like:  select dbo.ufnGENStripNonAlphaNumChars([your_column])

Comment: I managed to get it to work with adjusting your code-thanks! Only issue I've got now is that for example with the <p> tag it gets rid of all the just single p's as well. Do you know if I can declare the <p> tag as a whole somehow?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use charindex instead of patindex to more directly target html elements.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server