# How do I remove html tags in one of the column upon SELECT in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a view of a data table, but there is an issue which is there are html tags in the string of one of my columns (column7). **How can I remove all the tags and select only the text upon SELECT?**

The below is the similar sample code for my views:

```
SELECT  /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ DISTINCT 
    [column1],
    [column2],
    [column3],
    [column4],
    [column5],
    [column6],
    [column7],
    [column8],
    [column9]
    FROM SAMPLETABLE
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server might help you.

Comment: @zedfoxus Hi, Do you know how I can implement it with my SELECT statement that come with multiple columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a user defined function (UDF) like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

This is taken from [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server).

Then, run your SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
    [column1],
    [column2],
    [column3],
    [column4],
    [column5],
    [column6],
    udf_StripHTML([column7]) as col7, -- this is the column containing HTML you want to remove
    [column8],
    [column9]
FROM SAMPLETABLE
```

I don't have access to SQL Server right now so you'll just have to try it out.

Comment: Hi any idea how to remove &nbsp; from it as well?

Comment: Try `REPLACE(udf_StripHTML([column7]), '&nbsp;', '') as col7`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the tags you have in your column, you can convert it to XML and use XPath to retrieve the data.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ DISTINCT 
    [column1],
    [column2],
    [column3],
    [column4],
    [column5],
    [column6],
    CAST([column7]AS XML).value('(/p)[1]','nvarchar(1000)') AS column7,
    [column8],
    [column9]
    FROM SAMPLETABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

As zedfoxus said, see [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Then: avoid **DISTINCT** - it often means you have other query/JOIN issues hidden by a wasteful band-aid.

finally, give the [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] defined in the above referenced answer, then

```
SELECT   
    [dbo].[udf_StripHTML]([column1]) as column1,
    [dbo].[udf_StripHTML]([column2]) as column2,
      ....
    [dbo].[udf_StripHTML]([column9]) as column9

FROM dbo.SAMPLETABLE
```

Finally, if you need more performance, look into using a function loaded in a .NET CLR assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is variant with recursive cte

```
/* CREATING TEST TABLE */
declare @YourTable table (id int identity(1,1),StringWithTags varchar(100))
insert @YourTable (StringWithTags) values ('<p>hjsdbhs</p>'),('<p>cfsdv ;nbsp; </p>'),('without tag')

/* REMOVING TAGS */
;with cte as
(
    select id,1 CharID, substring(StringWithTags,1,1) Ch
        ,case when substring(StringWithTags,1,1) in ('<','&') then 'op' end TagType
        ,case when substring(StringWithTags,1,1) in ('<','&') then 1 else 0 end isInsideTag
    from @YourTable
    where len(StringWithTags)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id,c.CharID+1,substring(t.StringWithTags,CharID+1,1) Ch
        ,case when substring(t.StringWithTags,CharID+1,1) in ('<','&') then 'op' 
            else case when substring(t.StringWithTags,CharID+1,1) in ('>',';') then 'cl' end
         end TagType
         ,case when substring(t.StringWithTags,CharID+1,1) in ('<','&','>',';') then 1
               else case when c.isInsideTag=1 and ISNULL(c.TagType,'')<>'cl' then 1 else 0  end
          end isInsideTag
    FROM @YourTable t
         JOIN cte c ON c.id=t.id
    WHERE c.CharID+1<=len(StringWithTags)

)
select REPLACE(REPLACE((select REPLACE(c2.Ch,' ','[sp]') as 'data()' from cte c2 where c2.id=c.id and c2.isInsideTag=0 order by c2.id for xml path(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),' ',''),'[sp]',' ')
from cte c
group by id
order by c.id
```