# A function to get rid of all characters in-between two specific chars in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to go through a column of `varchar` and in each record I need get rid of everything in between the characters `<` and `>` (and remove the `<` and `>` characters).

So for example if the string in a record is:

```
"<120012012sasdcdf sadasd>help <rando mchars werewr>me<e randss>."
```

I should end up with: `"help me."`

If the next string is: `"hi <blah><blah>."`

Then I'll get: `hi.`

Is there a function that can help me do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to strip html tags from a string in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Comment: There is no way to do this in generic way with the pure SQL. You have refer to the particular implementation and RDBMS and use regexp

Comment: In your second example, why wouldn't the returned data be `hi .` Note the space.

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks that was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Of course in theory you can - SQL with recursive queries is Turing-complete language.

Your examples can be solved with a "parser" of sorts:

```
WITH STRT AS(
    SELECT SRC_STR = 'hi <blah><blah>.'
    --SELECT SRC_STR = '<120012012sasdcdf sadasd>help <rando mchars werewr>me<e randss>.'
),
REC AS (
    SELECT 
        N = 1
        ,LITERA = SUBSTRING(src_str,1,1)
        ,PREV_STATE = 
            CASE 
                WHEN SUBSTRING(src_str,1,1) = '<' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ,CUR_STATE = 
            CASE 
                WHEN SUBSTRING(src_str,1,1) = '<' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        FROM STRT
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        N = N + 1
        ,LITERA = SUBSTRING(src_str,N+1,1)
        ,PREV_STATE = CUR_STATE 
        ,CUR_STATE = 
            CASE
                WHEN SUBSTRING(src_str,N+1,1) = '<'
                        AND PREV_STATE = 0
                    THEN 1
                WHEN SUBSTRING(src_str,N+1,1) = '>' 
                     AND SUBSTRING(src_str,N+2,1) <> '<'
                    AND PREV_STATE = 1
                    THEN 0                  
                ELSE CUR_STATE
            END
    FROM REC,STRT
        WHERE
            N < LEN(src_str)
)
SELECT REPLACE(
    (SELECT '~' + LITERA 
        FROM REC
        WHERE
            PREV_STATE = CUR_STATE
            AND PREV_STATE = 0
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),'~','')
```

I strongly advise against using such code in production.

In theory you can write language compiler in SQL with recursive queries.

In practice - it's more suitable as toy task for interviews.

Comment: Thanks. I'll heed your warning as well.