# Remove a <img tag from the table using SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and my data and image is inserted from a richtextbox from asp.net and I need help to display only text, not image, from the specific field from the table.

Here is an example:-

```
<p>The Brando is an exquisite luxury resort on French Polynesia&rsquo;s breathtakingly beautiful private atoll of Tetiaroa,
   <img style="width: 100%;" src="../images/InfrastructureImage/The Brando, French Polynesia 2.jpgc05350ab-ba5d-465f-91da-4b9edb8fce47.jpg" 
  alt="The Brando, French Polynesia 2.jpg" />
</p>
```

into this example I want only text not image which is on the `<img>` tag I want to remove the complete image tag. I need help fetching only the text.

Please help me with this

Comment: You can use `html agility pack` [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Comment: In sql server you can use user define function [similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

In your dataLayer

```
Text = Regex.Replace(reader["Htmltext"] as string, "<img.*?>", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split and get. Not a clean process but its work.

```
string YourReceiveValue="<p>The Brando is an exquisite luxury resort on French Polynesia&rsquo;s breathtakingly beautiful private atoll of Tetiaroa,<img style="width: 100%;" src="../images/InfrastructureImage/The Brando, French Polynesia 2.jpgc05350ab-ba5d-465f-91da-4b9edb8fce47.jpg" alt="The Brando, French Polynesia 2.jpg" /></p>"
string[] result = YourReceiveValue.Split(new string[] { "<img" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string RemoveImage=result[0] + "</p>"; // Get back Closing tag of p
```