# Sql Server 2014 - Count Number of Word which contain HTML string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a **column** which contain following kind of data

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Now need to know the number of word in existing string.

**Questions are :**

1. **Is it possible** to achieve this thing in **sql server 2014.**
2. If possible then how can i **count exact word** from this string as this string **contain HTML tags also.**

Thanks in advance.

`<p>Hello World!</p>` is column value in database.

There can be different tags.

There can be a full html document with different and nested tags.

For particular this example output should 2.

Comment: what are you working at..? and is `<p>Hello World!</p>` a column's value in database? or what?

Comment: Yes Sir , <p>Hello World!</p> is a column value in database

Comment: Please add a bigger (realistic, but reduced to the minimum) HTML. Which tags? Is it XHTML?

Comment: No it is a simple HTML tag not XHTML

Comment: OK, but is it always just one `<p>something</p>` or might there be a full html document with different and nested tags?

Comment: is it only `<p>` tag or the whole html tags?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

No it always not just one <p>something</p> there might be a full html document with different nested tags.

Comment: So once again: Add a reduced to the necessary html and add the output you want to get.

Comment: Your edit provides absolutely no additional info. What are *different tags*? Do you need any word counted anywhere on the page?

Comment: Actually column consist html content i.e it may have <p> , <b> , <u> , <ol> , <li> tags. and i want number of word for that column only. Let say first row contain <p>Hi</p> then number should 1 , next row contain <b>Hi Hi</b> then number should 2

Comment: I found answer in following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server

Comment: I found answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Col VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @table (Col)
VALUES ('Hello To SQL')
    ,('oneword')
    ,('two words')
    ,('<p>Hello World!</p>')

SELECT col
    ,len(Col) - len(replace(col, ' ', '')) + 1 NumbofWords
FROM @table
```