# Removing specific text (HTML) from a query

Tags: html, sql

I'm running a query and one of the fields is returning with html, specifically

&  tags. I'd ideally love them to be removed.
Note: The tags are not just at the start & end of the results

```
SELECT distinct
Id, 
name, 
Date,
Note
FROM Activity
```

Results from Note column:

```
1<p>Test</p> 
2<p>Follow up to email </p> 
3<p>Good Morning Liz,</p>  <p> </p>  <p>I hope you’re well.</p>  <p> </p>  <p>I have just got out of meeting with my sales director and he has given some great fantastic offers for new clients.</p>  <p>Kindest Regards</p> 
4<p>Follow up</p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server