# Searching for a text in a string property where the value is HTML

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a field in my database (SQL Server) with the type of nvarchar(max) where its values are HTML (say an email's content).

I want to search through these values by a given text. I use `.net core` and `Entity framework` to make queries.

Of course, I can simply use `Contains` function but that also includes HTML tags. For example, if I search for the text "strong", it also matches those values that have strong HTML tag though they might not have the word strong in their content, which is not desirable.

```cs
var query = _dbContext.Emails.AsQueryable();

// The following code also searches through HTML tags
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
{
    query=query.Where(ent=>ent.Contents.Contains(searchText));
}
```

Is there an easy way to avoid HTML tags in the search, for example using Regex?

**UPDATE**

Ideally I want to do this in SQL server side when the query is `IQueryable` not `IEnumerable`, i.e., before calling `.ToList()`.

Comment: HTML is not regular and Regex is meant to parse Regular Expressions.  So we do not recommend using regex on html.  It is better to use an HTML library to get tags/data from html.

Comment: strip the html tags first. there are functions all over the net that do this.

Comment: Maybe use '>...<' so you only capture stuff between tags. That might of course still fail if you have nested tags so this is more of a starting point than a solution.

Comment: Use this SQL function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no easy answer in your case, but you have several possibilities. Regex can be a simple solution if you do not want to get the full tags. A more deeper but more complex would be to use a package like **HtmlAgilityPack** to parse your mail.

Here is an example of the regex :

```
var searchWord = "strong";
var mail = "<strong>blablabla</strong><p>blabla strong blabla</p>";
var rgx = new Regex($"(?!<){searchWord}(?!>)"); // Will match strong but not <strong> or <strong or strong>
if (rgx.IsMatch(mail))
{
    // Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if you can use free and open source [HtmlAgilityPack](https://github.com/linezero/HtmlAgilityPack) through which you can first convert the html text to plain text and then apply the search criteria.

E.g.: var plainTextResult = HtmlUtilities.ConvertToPlainText(string html);

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
{
    bool containsResult = plainTextResult.Contains(searchText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Amine and @lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs, I figured out how to do this.

First, I created a SQL function in my database that strips a given text:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnStripHTML] (@HTMLText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

Then I added a reference to that function in my `DbContext`:

```cs
        [DbFunction("ufnStripHTML")]
        public static string StripHTML(string text)
        {
            throw new Exception("not implemented");
        }
```

and now I can use it in my `Linq to SQL` query:

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
{
    query = query.Where(ent => TGDbContext.StripHTML(ent.Contents).Contains(searchText));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the regex function as am using below:

```
"<div>Hello</div><span>World</span>".replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')
```

Comment: What languege you are using here? It is not C#.

Comment: The example contains the regex that you require, It is just an example, I am sure you just use that regex into your C# code to replace the first Html then you can use IndexOf() function. I hope it makes sense. Don't give me negative feedback I am just trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh. I did not give you the negative feedback. Somebody else did!

Comment: @Mojtaba to you as well