# Sql query to replace all html tags from a column

Tags: sql

```
<para><bold>Arbitrator, Professor:</bold> 4350 Galewood Drive, P.O.Box 2029, Lake Oswego, OR 
97034. Res.: 751 Briercliff Lane, Lake Oswego,OR 97034. Born 1933. BS, Bus. Adm., Univ. of 
Ala., 1958; MS, Ind.Rels., Univ. of Ala., 1960; PhD, Lab. Eco., La. State Univ., 1969. 
</para><para><bold>Member:</bold> AAA, SPIDR, IRRA.</para><para><bold>Experience:</bold> 
Med., Oregon Conc. Serv., 1972-76;Inst., Portland State Univ.; Prof., So. Oregon State 
College, 1966-76.</para><para><bold>Arbitrator Public Sector Agencies:</bold> Oregon 
ERB,Montana Bd. Pers. Apps.; Hawaii PERB; Washington PERC; CaliforniaPERB; Idaho PERB; 
Oregon State Ed. System; Lane County, Oregon; CentralOregon Irrigation; City of Eugene. 
</para><para><bold>Issues:</bold> Work assignments, pay, job description,new contract terms, 
union security, discharge &amp; discipline, jobevaluation, seniority.</para><para>. 
<bold>Industries</bold>: Organizations, steel, extractive,retail &amp; chain stores, e 
electric power, metal fab., chemicals,petroleum, construction, health care, communications, 
transportation,pub. sec. gr., fed. sec., pub. sec. int.</para>
```

Above is the data in one of my sql table column.
The complete column has similar data.
I want to replace all the html tags with space through sql query.
i am not able to figure out the sql query for this.
What should be the correct sql query for such task.

Comment: There is already an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/457725/1131949

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)