# SQL - Convert / Cast and return original value if not successful

Tags: html, sql, metabase

I'm trying to remove html tags from a string in a column.
And I need kind of a fast quick solution that works.

I wanted to use this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60080639/9974143)

```
replace(replace(replace(CAST(CAST(replace([columnNameHere], '&', '&amp;') as xml).query('for $x in //. return concat((($x)//text())[1]," ")') as varchar(max)), '&amp;', '&'), '&nbsp;', ' '), '&#x20;', ' ')
```

But on some strings it fails with this error:

> Conversion of one or more characters from XML to target collation
> impossible

I don't have time to debug what input exactly causes it to fail, so I'd like to have an option to still use this solution, but if it fails, just return/keep the original value (with the html tags).

Is there such a way?

Comment: …why are you doing this in SQL?

Comment: A certain team needs a report with some data, and we are using a 3rd party system that only has sql as an option.

Comment: Please provide sample data that reproduces your issue, [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)