# Natural Sort in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using C# and SQL Server 2005.  I have a dataset with table numbers like so that I need to have a natural sort on:

```
 1
 10
 2
 I.1
 Table 1
 Table 2
 Table 10
 I.10
 I.2
```

Above is my numbers, and I want them to be sorted number first (1,2, ... , 10, 11), then by the alphabet (I.1, I.2, ... ,1.10, I.11, etc.) which would put Table 1, Table 2, ... , Table 10, ... at the end.

Is there any way to do this with some funky SQL?

(Note: I can't use a C# natural sort function as I can't load the entire dataset all at once.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural (human alpha-numeric) sort in Microsoft SQL 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this may work (untested, as I do not have an instance of SQL Server on the laptop I'm using):

```
  SELECT *
    FROM [tbl]
ORDER BY ISNUMERIC([col]) DESC,
         CASE ISNUMERIC([col])
              WHEN 1 THEN CAST([col] AS INT)
              ELSE [col]
              END ASC;
```

The `ISNUMERIC` function returns `1` if it thinks the value is a valid number, so:

- `ISNUMERIC([col]) DESC` puts numbers at the front
- `CASE ... END` sorts numbers numerically, and text values alphabetically.

You may need to fine tune this, but it should get you started down the right path.

Comment: throws error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'I.1' to data type int.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 
declare @a as table (name varchar(100))
insert into @a values ('1')
insert into @a values ('10')
insert into @a values ('2')
insert into @a values ('I.1')
insert into @a values ('Table 1')
insert into @a values ('Table 2')
insert into @a values ('Table 10')
insert into @a values ('I.10')
insert into @a values ('I.2')

select name from
(
select top 10 name 
from 
    (   select top 10 row_number() over (partition by numerics order by numerics desc) sono, numerics, name 
        from 
        (
            select isnumeric(name) numerics, name 
            from @a
        )t
    )s where numerics = 1 order by convert(decimal, name)
) a
union all
select name from
(
select top 10 name 
from 
    (
        select top 10 row_number() over (partition by numerics order by numerics desc) sono, numerics, name 
        from 
        (
            select isnumeric(name) numerics, name 
            from @a
        )u 
    ) v where numerics = 0 order by name
) b
```

Comment: The output is not write for. The output should have ordered in(1, 2, 10, I.1, I.2, I.10, Table 1, Table 2 , Table 10)