# Order By alphanumeric values like numeric

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

there is a table's fields on MSSQL Serrver 2005 as VARCHAR. It contains alphanumeric values like "A,B,C,D ... 1,2,3,...,10,11,12" etc.

When i use below codes;

```
....   
ORDER BY TableFiledName
```

**Ordering result is as follow** 11,12,1,2,3 etc.

When i use codes as below,

```
....   
 ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(TableFiledName) = 0 THEN CAST(TableFiledNameAS INT) ELSE TableFiledName END
```

I get error message as below;

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar
>   to float.

**How can get like this ordering result:** 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 etc..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are letters sorted? or they won;t show on the list?

Comment: Try this approach:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ISNUMERIC` returns 1 when the field is numeric.

So your first problem is that it should be ...

```
   CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(TableFiledName) = 1 THEN
```

But this alone won't work.

You need to prefix the values with zeroes and take the rightmost

```
 order by 
      case when ISNUMERIC(FieldName) =1 
      then right('000000000'+FieldName, 5)
      else FieldName 
      end
```

Using 5 allows for numbers up to 99999 - if your numbers are higher, increase that number.

This will put the numbers before the letters. If you want the letters before the numbers, then you can add an `isnumeric` to the sort order - ie:

```
 order by
      isnumeric(FieldName),
      case...
```

This won't cope with decimals, but you haven't mentioned them