# Sort Order on column with multiple decimal places

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Crystal Reports XI

I have a field that is of type nvarchar

it contains the contents of a book so the data is like

```
1 
3.3
1.1
4.5.6
1.4.3.1.1
11.2
....
```

How would I sort on this column such that it shows up on the report as

```
1
1.1
1.4.3.1.1
3.3
4.5.6
11.2
...
```

Comment: Try implementing a scalar CLR function...

You can find one possible implementation **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the max number of decimals then you could break apart the string into parts and sort on those individually. For example, if you know you'll only have a max of 4 decimals (separating 5 different numbers) then you could create 5 formulas each representing a piece of the string.

```
//Formula {@Num1} to isolate most significant number
local stringvar array splitString := split({table.string},'.');
if isnumeric(splitString[1]) then tonumber(splitString[1]) else 0

//...and the formula {@Num2} for second most significant number
local stringvar array splitString := split({table.string},'.');
if ubound(splitString)>1 and isnumeric(splitString[2])
  then tonumber(splitString[2]) else 0
```

Now sort your report first by `{@Num1}` and then by `{@Num2}` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response - this would have been perfect but the # of decimals is not fixed.

Comment: Number of decimals doesn't need to be fixed, you just need to know the maximum number of decimals. If the decimals don't exist for a particular row, use a 0 and it'll still sort correctly. For example, the string "11.2" will be sorted as 11.2.0.0.0

Comment: yes - that is what I meant (sorry) ... the maximum number of decimals is not a constant. I can sure set that to a high (say like 20 or so) - but is there a way we can get around that ?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to sort them in T-SQL by converting the values to [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES
    ('1'),
    ('3.3'),
    ('1.1'),
    ('4.5.6'),
    ('1.4.3.1.1'),
    ('11.2')
) v (version)
ORDER BY
  CAST('/' + version + '/' AS hierarchyid)
;
```

Please see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16288) for a demonstration.

Comment: Brilliant. I forgot about this new for 2008 data type.