# Sort String Containing number

Tags: sql-server

Current OutPut:

```
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_1_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_10_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_14_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_15_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_16_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_2_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_3_CLOSED
```

Expected Output:

```
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_1_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_2_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_3_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_10_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_14_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_15_CLOSED  
PM_DIG_OUTPUT_16_CLOSED
```

Index of Number is not fixed
What is the best way to achieve this order?

EDIT: 
Some records also contain following data
`PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO1

PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO2

PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO3

PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO4`

Comment: Do any of the methods in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005 help you?

Comment: and what expected result on all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that after the number there's only one underscore and some text (then no matter what is before the number, if it's at least one underscore and some text).

Edit for new values. It will sort by the numbers if it can find them and won't break if no numbers were found by matching the pattern:

```
select 
    *,
    substring(y,len(y)-charindex('_',reverse(y))+2,100) as num
from (
    select
        *,
        substring(x,1,len(x)-charindex('_',reverse(x))) as y
    from (
        select 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_1_CLOSED' as x union all
        select 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_10_CLOSED' union all
        select 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_14_CLOSED' union all
        select 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_15_CLOSED' union all
        select 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_16_CLOSED' union all
        select 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_2_CLOSED' union all
        select 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_3_CLOSED' union all 
        select 'PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO1' union all
        select 'PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO2' union all
        select 'PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO3' union all
        select 'PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO4'        
    ) x
) y
order by 
    case when isnumeric(substring(y,len(y)-charindex('_',reverse(y))+2,100))=1 then cast(substring(y,len(y)-charindex('_',reverse(y))+2,100) as int) end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, Its working fine for sample data which I provided in question but failing for some records like PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO1  
PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO2  
PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO3  
PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO4

Comment: @RahulPatel You didn't exactly say what's the rule for extracting the number. Even in example from your comment, there are two numbers. By which one the two results should be sorted?

Comment: Thanks for the update.Yes, This is what I was looking for. Also, After Analysis of more records from my Database I found few more patterns.So, I realized that I need to change some records itself to fit for a sorting pattern.

Comment: @RahulPatel Or you could go with CLR functions and RegEx. Would be much better than this mess :).

Answer (score 5):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a718a/5)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_', ''),'_CLOSED', '') AS int)
```

Result:

```
|                     COL |
|-------------------------|
|  PM_DIG_OUTPUT_1_CLOSED |
|  PM_DIG_OUTPUT_2_CLOSED |
|  PM_DIG_OUTPUT_3_CLOSED |
| PM_DIG_OUTPUT_10_CLOSED |
| PM_DIG_OUTPUT_14_CLOSED |
| PM_DIG_OUTPUT_15_CLOSED |
| PM_DIG_OUTPUT_16_CLOSED |
```

**EDITED ANSWER**

You could use query:
**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79557/5)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(col, 2) = 'PM' 
              THEN CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, 'PM_DIG_OUTPUT_', ''),'_CLOSED', '') AS int)
              ELSE RIGHT(col,1) END
```

Result:

```
|                                           COL |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|                        PM_DIG_OUTPUT_1_CLOSED |
| PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO1 |
| PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO2 |
|                        PM_DIG_OUTPUT_2_CLOSED |
|                        PM_DIG_OUTPUT_3_CLOSED |
| PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO3 |
| PRM_CODE_MIO_DIGITALOUT_WRITE_LOGIC_CARD2_DO4 |
|                       PM_DIG_OUTPUT_10_CLOSED |
|                       PM_DIG_OUTPUT_14_CLOSED |
|                       PM_DIG_OUTPUT_15_CLOSED |
|                       PM_DIG_OUTPUT_16_CLOSED |
```

Comment: Thanks Justin for your Answer but I can't use this as Its not the case when result will always contain "PM_DIG_OUTPUT_" and "_CLOSED"

Comment: @RahulPatel and what expected result on all data??

Comment: Thank you Justin, I got the expected output from frikozoid's answer