# How to effectively sort nvarchar containing numbers and letters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some troubles sorting a table effectively (the table contains a big amount of rows so any optimization would make a big difference).

What I currently have that gives the correct result (11) is the code below.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    CREATE TABLE #tPallets
    (
      PalletNumber bigint,
      Placement nvarchar(4)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100000, 'B')   
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100001, 'M1')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100002, 'M2')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100003, 'M3')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100004, 'M4')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100005, 'M5')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100006, 'M6')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100007, 'M7')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100008, 'M8')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100009, 'M9')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100010, 'M10')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100011, 'M11')  

    SELECT 
        TOP 1 CASE 
            WHEN Placement LIKE 'M%' THEN CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(Placement,2, len(Placement)-1)) 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS PALLET_PLACEMENT 
    FROM 
        #tPallets 
    ORDER BY 
        1 DESC

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

So I am looking for a way to make the select faster if that's possible in this specific scenario.

---

I wouldn't consider this a duplicate in the way of answers. Since no answer in the thread would make the execution time faster without making the sort in C# (as opposed to doing it in TSql). And I have a hard time believing that there is no faster way to do it in TSql itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural (human alpha-numeric) sort in Microsoft SQL 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005)

Comment: Is the structure of the values consistent? Always 1 letter and then 0 - 2 digits? Are the letters always upper-case? And does the `Placement` value ever change?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky It's always B or M1 - M150 (at worst). Sorry for the very late answer, didn't see the comment.

Answer (score 0):

with what detail you hv provided,try this  way.

```
CREATE TABLE #tPallets
    (
      PalletNumber bigint,
      Placement nvarchar(4),
      OrderBy as CASE 
            WHEN Placement LIKE 'M%' THEN CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(Placement,2, len(Placement)-1)) 
            ELSE 0 END
    )

    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100000, 'B')   
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100001, 'M1')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100002, 'M2')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100003, 'M3')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100004, 'M4')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100005, 'M5')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100006, 'M6')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100007, 'M7')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100008, 'M8')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100009, 'M9')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100010, 'M10')  
    INSERT INTO #tPallets  VALUES(100011, 'M11')  

    select * from #tPallets
    order by OrderBy
```

Alternatively try this but not sure.

```
select * from #tPallets
order by BINARY_CHECKSUM(Placement) desc
```

Comment: This is exactly as fast and wouldn't apply to the real query. I'm looking for a replacement to the Convert / substring / len that is faster.

Comment: Even if you make computed column `persisted`?

Comment: It doesn't give the answer that I am looking for. When I add the case in the select instead of * they are exactly as fast. The answer I want in the end is 11 in this case.

Comment: @Danieboy , i think create clustered index on computed column is the only way .Why you will want to order so much data at one time ?

Answer (score 0):

An index on a computed column https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns

or, perhaps better in your situation a combination of that and filtered index

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes

to get rid of those pesky 0s.  (What are your expectations of order when your `placement` is not `like %M` by the way?)

Comment: At the start there is only a 'B' which should be seen as number 0. So that the query returns 0 in that case.

Comment: Sure but it's about selectivity.  If you have effectively `ORDER BY 0` then you will not be able to determine the `TOP 1` unless you specify some other criteria.  You will get *a* row but you won't know which one.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction with that last comment. I realized that in this scenarion MAX() was way faster than TOP 1 / ORDER BY 1 DESC.

Comment: And while you may be correct in that this index could possibly make this query faster...I don't think it's desirable in this specific scenarion (outside of a temporary table). Because there are tons of different queries on the same table which need other indexes. And as I understand it you don't want too many indexes on a table. Is this correct?

Comment: More indexes slow down inserts & updates not selects.  The more you have the slower your inserts & updates but if you need them then you need them.  Observe, measure, decide. It's always a trade off.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a Computed Column**
The way to speed it up is to have the column be persisted than you can create an index on your column. Keep in mind this of course will have a performance penalty on DML (insert/updates/deletes)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tPallets
CREATE TABLE #tPallets
(
    PalletNumber bigint,
    Placement nvarchar(4),
    PALLET_PLACEMENT AS (CASE 
        WHEN Placement LIKE 'M%' THEN CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(Placement,2, len(Placement)-1)) 
        ELSE 0 
    END) PERSISTED /*Will save the calculation in the table*/
)

INSERT INTO #tPallets
VALUES(100000, 'B')   
,(100001, 'M1')  
,(100002, 'M2')  
,(100003, 'M3')  
,(100004, 'M4')  
,(100005, 'M5')  
,(100006, 'M6')  
,(100007, 'M7')  
,(100008, 'M8')  
,(100009, 'M9')  
,(100010, 'M10')  
,(100011, 'M11')  

/*Can create this to speed up the query*/
CREATE INDEX ix_test on #tPallets (PALLET_PLACEMENT) INCLUDE (PalletNumber,Placement)

SELECT *
FROM  #tPallets 
ORDER BY PALLET_PLACEMENT DESC
```