# SQL Server sort by letters first then numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying for the past 2/3 hours to sort a varchar the way I want it, but I could not figure it out. Basically this is the query that comes the closest to what I want:

```
select Plantmaat
from Plant
Group by Plantmaat
order by (CASE WHEN Plantmaat like '[a-z]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), Plantmaat ASC;
```

Outputs this:

```
LEV
PLG
S 10-12
S 12-14
S 14-16
S 16-18
UITS
10
-10
11
12
14
15
-9
```

But this is what I want to achieve:

```
LEV
PLG
UITS
S 10-12
S 12-14
S 14-16
S 16-18
-9
-10
10
11
12
14
15
```

AS you can see the biggest problem here is that it doesn't sort the row that has only letters, and that negative numbers end up at the bottom.

Comment: Ideally fix your design, don't store numerical data in a `varchar` column.

Comment: If you want you numbers in ascending order, why would you have `-9` before `-10`? Shouldn't it be the other way around? And why should a string starting with `U` be before a string starting with `S`? The main problem is, that the column you are sorting by is a varchar. So order is done lexiographically. You will also discover, that 100 will be sorted before 20

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34509/87698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to match your logic:

```
select *
from tab
order by
  case when col not like '%[0-9-]%' then 0 else 1 end -- no digits
 ,case when col like '[^0-9-]%' then 0 else 1 end     -- starting with non-digit
 ,case when col like '-%' then 0 else 1 end           -- negative values first
 ,len(col)                                            -- shorter (=smaller) values first
 ,col
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39f81abd0d39a578f5c0f91b6f484a73)

Answer (score 0):

The best I can suggest is the following, however, it will *not* give you result you want:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,YourVarchar) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,YourVarchar) IS NULL THEN YourVarchar ELSE NULL END
         TRY_CONVERT(int,YourVarchar);
```

As i mentioned, this won't give the results in your question, for the reasons  [derpirscher highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116149/sql-server-sort-by-letters-first-then-numbers#comment113379505_64116149). For strings, `'U'` has a "higher" value than `'S'` and `'P'` so will ordered after **both** of them, not after `'P'` and before `'S'`.

For numbers, the number `-9` is *larger* than  `-10`, and so will be ordered after it as well, not before.

As I mentioned, however, the *real* solution here is fix your design. If you are mixing both numerical and string data in the same column, and want numerical data to behave like a numerical value, then you need 2 columns; one for the string data one for the numerical data.

If, however, you don't want numerical data to behave like a numerical value (so `'2'` is "greater" than `'10'`, and `'4' + '7'` is `'47'` ) then a `varchar` is fine, but you can't then expect it to ever act like a numerical value unless you change your design.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. I understand the way I want it sorted is pretty much impossible, but I wanted to give it a try. However, 2 seperate columns is not really an option for me unfortunately. Thanks again for your answer, I learned something again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers in *numeric* order, then you want -10 before -9.  If this is what you really want, then you can use:

```
select *
from tab
order by try_convert(int, col), col;
```

If you really do want -9 first, you can tweak this:

```
select *
from tab
order by sign(try_convert(int, col)),
         abs(try_convert(int, col)), col;
```