# Order by not giving expected results in SQL Server select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have select statement  table with two columns, `storebusinesskey` and `businessdate`.

When I run a select and try to sort the output by `storebusinesskey`, it's not working.

```
SELECT
    t1.StoreBusinessKey, DateBusinessKey AS BusinessDate
FROM
    TABA t1
LEFT JOIN 
    TABB t2 ON t1.StoreBusinessKey = t2.StoreBusinessKey 
            AND t1.DateBusinessKey = t2.BusinessDate
WHERE
    t2.BusinessDate IS NULL
ORDER BY
    t1.StoreBusinessKey DESC
```

Output

| StoreBusinessKey | BusinessDate |
| --- | --- |
| C95 | 2022-03-15 |
| C91 | 2022-03-27 |
| C89 | 2022-03-09 |
| C784 | 2022-03-22 |
| C784 | 2022-03-15 |
| C766 | 2022-03-22 |
| C766 | 2022-03-29 |
| C759 | 2022-03-22 |
| C693 | 2022-03-22 |
| C681 | 2022-03-22 |
| C674 | 2022-03-30 |
| C654 | 2022-03-30 |
| C606 | 2022-03-30 |
| C595 | 2022-03-29 |
| C595 | 2022-03-30 |
| C56 | 2022-03-30 |
| C521 | 2022-03-30 |
| C52 | 2022-03-30 |
| C486 | 2022-03-27 |
| C486 | 2022-03-30 |
| C486 | 2022-03-26 |
| C486 | 2022-03-29 |
| C486 | 2022-03-28 |
| C476 | 2022-03-29 |
| C476 | 2022-03-30 |
| C471 | 2022-03-30 |

As you can see C52 should come in top but it's not. Can you please help me to sort this output by `Storebusinesskey` first and then by `businessdate`?

Comment: `C52 should come in top` - you mean bottom, right? (You are ordering `DESC`.) Or is `C52` > `C95` for other reasons?

Comment: There is no reason SQL Server should do this with normal sort rules. WHat you are looking for is called Natural Sort. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sorting on the string value.  Assuming one leading alpha and with a little string manipulation, we can easily convert to an int and sort

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([StoreBusinessKey] varchar(50),[BusinessDate] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('C95','2022-03-15')
,('C91','2022-03-27')
,('C89','2022-03-09')
,('C784','2022-03-22')
,('C784','2022-03-15')
,('C52','2022-03-30')   -- Should be first
 
Select * 
 From  @YourTable
 Order By try_convert(int,substring([StoreBusinessKey],2,25))
         ,[BusinessDate]
```

**Results**

```
StoreBusinessKey    BusinessDate
C52                 2022-03-30
C89                 2022-03-09
C91                 2022-03-27
C95                 2022-03-15
C784                2022-03-15
C784                2022-03-22
```

Comment: You are the MAN . It's working as I want. Thanks a lot.But when I put this query in my SSRS report ,most of the data get sorted but still few are not sorting on busniessdate.


| StoreBusinessKey | BusinessDate |
|-------------------|--------------|
|C784 |3/15/2022|
|C784 |3/31/2022|
|C784 |3/22/2022|