# How can I sort my non numeric data from SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with sorting in SQL.

Data:

```
ID   accountCode
1     A99
2     A3792
3     A230
4     A2
5     AA2
6     AB23
7     EXMPLECODE
```

Query:

```
select top 1 accountCode
from AccountCodes
where accountCode like 'A%'
order by accountCode desc
```

Result:

```
A99
```

Expected Result:

```
A379
```

How can I get A379 result in this stuation?

Thank you for help

Comment: Remove the A, cast as integer.

Comment: The sort you are getting in your `RESULT:` is called "Lexicographical" which is how a dictionary would sort, and it's how an alpha or alpha numeric string is sorted by pretty much any sorting algorithm. "A99" would be, in the dictionary, after "A379". Instead you want to sort these numerically, which means you need to turn them into a number (cut off the A, cast to a number, and sort).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Natural (human alpha-numeric) sort in Microsoft SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005)

Comment: If your format is guaranteed to *always* be "single letter + number", a simple solution would be `ORDER BY LEN(accountCode) DESC, accountCode DESC`.

Comment: I see you have several answers to the problem. This type of question often actually is an indication that normalization has been violated. It almost always means that the column is storing two pieces of information. This violates 1NF.

Answer (score 0):

substring into number, cast, then sort

```
select top 1 accountCode
from AccountCodes
where accountCode like 'A%'
order by CAST(SUBSTRING(accountCode, 2) AS INT) desc
```

Comment: I think substring is missing one argument.

Comment: It defaults to end of string

Comment: Thought it might, haven't used it much. But Fiddle didn't like it so thought I would mention it. Update: I used Sql Server in Fiddle.

Comment: I thought it might also and checked it to be true in mysql 5.7

Comment: But its not true for SQL Server which is what the question is tagged

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the all non numeric characters and then cast it as integer

```
CREATE TABLE AccountCodes
    ([ID] int, [accountCode] varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO AccountCodes
    ([ID], [accountCode])
VALUES
    (1, 'A99'),
    (2, 'A379'),
    (3, 'A230')
;
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
select top 1 accountCode
from AccountCodes
where accountCode like 'A%'
order by CAST(stuff(accountCode, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', accountCode)-1, '') as INT) desc
```

| accountCode |
| --- |
| A379 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GfJbdPPt)

Comment: This solution it work thanks. but ı forgot to write sometimes data is change 
for example A2323 A23 A21333 
how can ı optimize query for this situation ?

Comment: you changed your data, which is not allowed here, as it is a new question, and the proper way is to accept this one and ask a new question, still when you change your data you have to say which is the wanted result

Comment: I am sorry about the changed data. I am new here. I want to the same result A379

Comment: And what is the logic 379 is not the highest number, nor is is in any way sortable, you need always an algorithm that can be programmed

Answer (score 0):

Suppose #AccountCodes is your real table,

```
CREATE TABLE #AccountCodes
    ( [accountCode] varchar(30))
;
    
INSERT INTO #AccountCodes
    ([accountCode])
VALUES
    ( 'A99'),
    ( 'A379'),
    ( 'A230'),
    ('A2323'),
    ('A23'),
    ('A21333'),
    ('AB23'),
    ('EXMPLECODE')
;
```

Now create one #temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #temp  (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, [accountCode] varchar(30))

insert into #temp([accountCode])
select  accountcode from
(
select *
,cast(substring(accountcode,(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',accountcode)),len(accountcode)) as int)newCode
from #AccountCodes
where PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',accountcode)>0
)t4
order by newCode

insert into #temp([accountCode])
select [accountCode]
from #AccountCodes
where PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',accountcode)<=0
order by [accountCode]


select * from #temp order by id

drop table #AccountCodes,#temp
```

You can throw sample data where it not working

Answer (score 0):

we're extracting all the numbers from `accountCode`, ordering by the length of the number and then by the digits.

```
select   top 1 accountCode
from     t
where    accountCode like 'A%'
order by len(substring(accountCode, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', accountCode), len(accountCode))) desc, substring(accountCode, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', accountCode), len(accountCode)) desc
```

| accountCode |
| --- |
| A379 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BFsPRMDs?hide=2)

Answer (score -2):

In your query you're selecting the top 1 result where the accountCode is like "A%" which is obviously going to pick the first result: A99. You either have to change it to "A___%" or substring and sort.